# Stomach cancer - as bad as it looks?

Tags: cancer, stomach, second-opinion

Sadly where I live, healthcare is not so good, so I am a bit sceptical since several of my friends with serious illness were misdiagnosed in the past.

Recently my grandmother was diagnosed with stomach cancer.
The doctor only gave us some basic and short answers, so I decided to ask some professionals of their opinion; this is why I'm here.

I did some research on google but found nothing.

My question is, if I want to learn about it and do some more research, where should I start, what should I search for? Maybe some links would be useful about some similar cases,

Comment: In its current form, your question is off-topic: We cannot - and will not - give personal medical advice, only a doctor with your full medical background can. The only way to prevent your question from getting closed as being off-topic is removing the images and the personal detail and focus on the *where should I start to learn about stomach cancer*. I wish your grandmother the best!

Comment: I edited the question for the reasons @Narusan explained.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Without the pictures I don't think anyone can answer my question. What if I edit my question to something like "I'd like to learn more about what is on the picture for education, etc." I really tried to stay on-topic and I just need a direction where to start my research... I don't know the terminology. There must be a keyword or a name that I can look for. anything.

Comment: Why does anyone need to see pictures to answer your question? Your question is where to go to learn and research stomach cancer. Nobody needs pictures to answer that. Look, I know you're hoping some oncologist is going to see this and tell you all about your mother's condition, but that's not going to happen. It's not going to happen because it's just not possible. Nobody can diagnose her from those photos, and nobody can tell you how advanced it is or what treatment she needs because they know nothing about her.

Answer (score 2):

You said you went to google and found nothing. I find that puzzling because I went to google, typed in "stomach cancer" and found a wealth of info. Here's a sampling:

https://www.cancer.gov/types/stomach

http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/stomach-cancer/home/ovc-2020232

http://www.webmd.com/cancer/stomach-gastric-cancer#1

http://www.medicinenet.com/stomach_cancer/article.htm

And of course there's always Wikipedia, and it has a ton of references at the bottom of the article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomach_cancer

But one thing you need to keep in mind is that nobody on the internet can tell you anything about your grandmother. You really need to get that directly from her doctor, who is the only one who can tell you exactly what she has, what her prognosis is, and how he intends to treat it.

Comment: No, I was hoping for someone who has some basic understanding of the situation (unlike me) to point me into the right direction to what I am facing here. When I said I did not find anything similar on google, I was referring to the pictures. I found pictures of stomach cancer but none of them looked like the ones I posted here. The answer you provided gives me some reliable information at least. When I get home from work I will research what you gave me. So thank you.

Comment: @Divin3 Looking at medical imaging and deciding whether pictures are similar takes years of study and practice and if you are not a doctor I wouldn't try to do that. As a pharmacist I stare blankly at most of such images and have no idea what I'm looking at. As for the insight into your grandma's situation: we can't have any, since we never met her. Giving advice over the internet can do more harm than good. Under the first link Carey provided you have "General resources on coping" you might start there and read how to give moral support to your grandmother - every cancer patient needs it.